# How can I merge the results of a group by Linq-to-XML query?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to construct a Linq-to-XML query that performs the following steps:

1. groups all descendant nodes in an XDocument
2. aggregates the distinct items in each group
3. replaces the elements in the parent of the last item in each group with the aggregated items, in an order of my choosing
4. deletes all the original items in each group

So far I have the first two steps working with the following code. Note that the MyGroupByKeyFunction is written in a way that guarantees (among other things) that all elements in each group will have the same depth (this is why the orderby works).

```
var groups =
    from e in doc.Root.Descendants()
    group e by MyGroupByKeyFunction(e) into g
    orderby g.First().Ancestors().Count() descending
    select new {
        agg = g.Aggregate(new List<XElement>(), (list, el) => {
            list.Add(el);
            return list;
        }).Distinct(new MyCustomXElementEqualityComparer()),
        items = g,
        target = g.Last().Parent
    };
```

The last two steps are where I am getting stuck. I tried the following but it is not working quite the way I want.

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    group.items.Remove();
    foreach (var item in group.merge)
    {
        group.target.Add(item);
    }
 }
```

The elements in group.items are successfully removed and the target populated, but I also want the parent elements for the elements in group.items to be removed if the call to group.items.Remove() causes the parent to be emptied. So, I tried replacing that line with the following:

```
foreach (var delete in group.items)
{
    if (delete.Parent.Elements().Count() == 1)
        delete.Parent.Remove();

    else
        delete.Remove();
}
```

The problem with this is that successive iterations of this loop result can result in a NullReferenceException because the parent element may exist as an item in another group from the original query results! This of course causes delete.Parent to be null because it has previously been detached from the XML tree.

How can I get around this problem?

**Update**

Per Falanor's suggestion, I have tried modifying the code to the following. However, this causes the final result of the XDocument to only contain the root element. I can't figure out why that is happening. Any thoughts or a better solution to this problem?

```
HashSet<XElement> removed = new HashSet<XElement>();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    removed.UnionWith(group.items.Select(el => el.Parent).Where(el => !el.Parent.Equals(group.target)));
    group.items.Remove();
    foreach (var item in group.merge)
    {
        if (!removed.Contains(item))
            group.target.Add(item);
    }
}

removed.Where(el => el.Parent != null).Remove();
```

Comment: Just a minor style point, the ```g.Aggregate(...).Distinct()``` would be better expressed as ```g.Distinct().ToList(...)```

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized you could execute the query that way. That definitely makes the code more concise (and probably more efficient too, no?)

Comment: On second thought... oddly enough when I tried this, the execution time of my code was significantly increased... by a factor of about 20. Any idea why it takes so much longer than using Aggregate as I originally had in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Falanor's ideas was right, I just had a small error in the way I wrote the solution that caused it not to work. The method call to UnionWith should have been:

```
removed.UnionWith(group.items.Select(el => el.Parent).Where(el => !el.Equals(group.target)));
```

Note the error was in the where clause.

Also, for anyone interested, I realized I could significantly reduce the execution time of my code by adding the following 'where' clause to my initial query (right before the final 'select' statement):

```
where g.Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().Count() > 1
```

This causes the query to only return groupings of elements that belong to different parents. Just to put things in perspective, the XML file I was targeting my code with returned more than 200,000 groupings. With the additional 'where' clause, the number of groupings fell to about 150! And the final result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the parents(and the children as well) doing this?

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
if(group.Parent.Elements().Count() == 1)
group.Parent.Remove();
else
group.items.Remove();
foreach (var item in group.merge)
{
    group.target.Add(item);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this but don't think it can work since group is an Enumerable of anonymous type, so it has no single parent. Unfortunately, I also can't guarantee that all the elements in in the group.items member have the same parent element...

Comment: Consider looping through and deleting all empty nodes after the fact?

Comment: You may be on to something with that but when I tried to implement your suggestion it is resulting in an unintended consequence of removing all elements except the root. See my update for more information.